# How to plot Line chart with duplicate dates values?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am little struggling, as I am unsure how to go about implementing duplicate date values using google 'Line charts'.

This is what I have so far:

```
function drawVisualization(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
    if (dataValues.length < 1)
        return;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
    data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
    data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2]);
    data.addColumn('datetime', columnNames.split(',')[3]);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

        var date = new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].Date.substr(6), 10));

        //var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        //var date = new Date(new Number(jsonDate.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
        //var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
        alert(date);

        data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value, dataValues[i].Type, date]);

    }

    // Define a Pie chart
    var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'containerId': 'PieChartContainer',
        'options': {
            'width': 950,
            'height': 450,
            'legend': 'right',
            'hAxis': {
             'format': "dd-MMM-yyyy",
             'maxValue': new Date (2013, 01, 17), 'minValue': new Date (2013, 01, 10), 
             'viewWindow':{'max': new Date (2013, 01, 17)},
              },
            'title': chartTitle,
            'chartArea': { 'left': 100, 'top': 100, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 100 },
            'pieSliceText': 'label',
            'tooltip': { 'text': 'percentage' }
        },
        'view': { 'columns': [3, 1] }
    });
```

I have added 'hAxis' option to the charts but I getting 'object function not recognised' error.  Is their a better way around this task?  Any framework or guide would be very helpful.

For further reference this what kind of data I am using on the server-side to plot this:

```
79.00   06/03/2013
15.00   06/03/2013
14.00   06/03/2013
20.00   06/03/2013
22.00   06/03/2013
92.13   06/03/2013
(I have 20 points for date 2013-01-16 and 10 points for date 2013-01-17)
```

Updated charts visual after the 'hAxis' update:

[image]

can the intervals for the dates be distributed using controller such as 'dateRangeSlider'?

Many thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates on this line are constructed wrong:

```
'maxValue': date (2013, 01, 16), 'minValue': date (2013, 01, 17), 'viewWindow':{'max': date (2013, 01, 17)}},
```

Those should be in the format `new Date(year, month, day)`:

```
'maxValue': new Date (2013, 01, 16), 'minValue': new Date (2013, 01, 17), 'viewWindow':{'max': new Date (2013, 01, 17)}},
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response and help.  your suggestion solved the issue but Its outputting the line charts in compressed format, how can I make the date value be distributed to give ore details view of the graph.  is it possible to use 'date Range filter' control?  I have updated my original post for further reference to this issue. Many thanks. I am very grateful to your help and time.

Comment: What would you like the chart to look like?  If you want to keep it a LineChart like this, but show the data points, you can set the `pointSize` option for the chart to make the points bigger (`pointSize` takes an integer value for the radius of the point to draw in pixels, default is `0`).